# Android application does not show latitude and longitude coordinates when prompted

Tags: java, android, google-maps, gps

a simple application that displays the latitude and longitude in a textview; for some reason it does not display the relevant data. ive provided the java code, xml, manifesta and logcat.
code

```
package com.example.trucktracker;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.os.Build;

public class Locator extends ActionBarActivity {
     TextView textLat;
     TextView textLong;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_locator);
        textLat = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textLat);
        textLong = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textLong);
        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        LocationListener ll = new locatorlistener();
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, ll);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) 
        {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }
    class locatorlistener implements LocationListener
    {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            if(location != null)
            {
                double pLong = location.getLongitude();
                double pLat = location.getLatitude();
                textLat.setText(Double.toString(pLat));
                textLong.setText(Double.toString(pLong));
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_locator);
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.locator, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_locator,
                    container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.trucktracker.Locator"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/latitudetext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/latitude"
        tools:context=".Locator" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/logitudetext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/latitudetext"
        android:text="@string/longitude" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textLat"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/logitudetext"
        android:text=""
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/latitudetext" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textLong"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/logitudetext"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/logitudetext"
        android:text=""
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/logitudetext"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

manifest file

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

logcat

```
07-02 06:08:17.344: D/dalvikvm(535): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 90K, 4% free 8346K/8648K, paused 62ms, total 69ms
07-02 06:08:17.464: I/Choreographer(535): Skipped 321 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-02 06:08:17.714: D/dalvikvm(535): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 44K, 4% free 9914K/10224K, paused 63ms, total 64ms
07-02 06:08:17.884: I/Choreographer(535): Skipped 84 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-02 06:08:25.444: I/Choreographer(535): Skipped 41 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-02 06:08:25.614: I/Choreographer(535): Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-02 06:08:26.204: D/dalvikvm(535): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1404K, 15% free 9566K/11136K, paused 95ms, total 97ms
07-02 06:08:26.214: I/dalvikvm-heap(535): Grow heap (frag case) to 10.659MB for 1307824-byte allocation
07-02 06:08:26.284: D/dalvikvm(535): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 13% free 10841K/12416K, paused 78ms, total 78ms
07-02 06:08:26.424: I/Choreographer(535): Skipped 81 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-02 06:08:27.854: E/SoundPool(381): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-02 06:08:27.854: W/AudioService(381): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-02 06:08:27.854: E/SoundPool(381): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-02 06:08:27.864: W/AudioService(381): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-02 06:08:27.884: E/SoundPool(381): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-02 06:08:27.894: W/AudioService(381): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-02 06:08:27.894: E/SoundPool(381): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-02 06:08:27.894: W/AudioService(381): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-02 06:08:27.914: I/ActivityManager(381): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.example.trucktracker/.MainActivity} from pid 535
07-02 06:08:27.964: E/SoundPool(381): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-02 06:08:28.014: W/AudioService(381): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-02 06:08:28.014: E/SoundPool(381): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
07-02 06:08:28.014: W/AudioService(381): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
07-02 06:08:28.014: E/SoundPool(381): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
07-02 06:08:28.024: W/AudioService(381): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
07-02 06:08:28.024: E/SoundPool(381): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
07-02 06:08:28.024: W/AudioService(381): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
07-02 06:08:28.024: E/SoundPool(381): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
07-02 06:08:28.024: W/AudioService(381): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
07-02 06:08:28.024: E/SoundPool(381): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
07-02 06:08:28.024: W/AudioService(381): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
07-02 06:08:28.024: W/AudioService(381): onLoadSoundEffects(), Error -1 while loading samples
07-02 06:08:28.124: D/gralloc(49): Registering a buffer in the process that created it. This may cause memory ordering problems.
07-02 06:08:28.124: E/libEGL(49): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
07-02 06:08:28.124: E/libEGL(49): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
07-02 06:08:28.124: E/libEGL(49): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
07-02 06:08:28.134: E/libEGL(49): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
07-02 06:08:28.134: E/SurfaceFlinger(49): glCheckFramebufferStatusOES error -190605487
07-02 06:08:28.134: E/SurfaceFlinger(49): got GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_OES error while taking screenshot
07-02 06:08:28.134: E/libEGL(49): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
07-02 06:08:28.144: E/libEGL(49): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
07-02 06:08:28.184: W/WindowManager(381): Screenshot failure taking screenshot for (246x410) to layer 21005
07-02 06:08:28.254: I/Choreographer(535): Skipped 97 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-02 06:08:28.774: I/ActivityManager(381): Start proc com.example.trucktracker for activity com.example.trucktracker/.MainActivity: pid=1104 uid=10052 gids={50052}
07-02 06:08:28.854: D/dalvikvm(1104): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
07-02 06:08:30.864: I/Choreographer(535): Skipped 42 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-02 06:08:31.134: I/Choreographer(381): Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-02 06:08:31.204: I/ARMAssembler(49): generated scanline__00000077:03010104_00008001_00000000 [ 89 ipp] (110 ins) at [0xb6199680:0xb6199838] in 10000000 ns
07-02 06:08:31.294: I/Choreographer(381): Skipped 40 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-02 06:08:32.064: D/dalvikvm(1104): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 67K, 5% free 3135K/3276K, paused 50ms, total 54ms
07-02 06:08:32.064: I/dalvikvm-heap(1104): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.758MB for 659360-byte allocation
07-02 06:08:32.174: D/dalvikvm(1104): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 6K, 4% free 3773K/3920K, paused 77ms, total 77ms
07-02 06:08:32.294: D/com.example.trucktracker.MainActivity(1104): Settings Text.
07-02 06:08:32.664: D/com.example.trucktracker.MainActivity(1104): Showing menu.
07-02 06:08:32.764: D/gralloc_goldfish(1104): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
07-02 06:08:32.974: I/ActivityManager(381): Displayed com.example.trucktracker/.MainActivity: +4s304ms
07-02 06:08:36.234: D/com.example.trucktracker.MainActivity(1104): ClickedContinueButton
07-02 06:08:36.234: I/ActivityManager(381): START u0 {cmp=com.example.trucktracker/.Locator} from pid 1104
07-02 06:08:36.244: E/SoundPool(381): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-02 06:08:36.244: W/AudioService(381): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-02 06:08:36.244: E/SoundPool(381): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-02 06:08:36.254: W/AudioService(381): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-02 06:08:36.254: E/SoundPool(381): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-02 06:08:36.254: W/AudioService(381): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-02 06:08:36.254: E/SoundPool(381): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-02 06:08:36.254: W/AudioService(381): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-02 06:08:36.254: E/SoundPool(381): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-02 06:08:36.254: W/AudioService(381): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-02 06:08:36.254: E/SoundPool(381): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
07-02 06:08:36.254: W/AudioService(381): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
07-02 06:08:36.254: E/SoundPool(381): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
07-02 06:08:36.254: W/AudioService(381): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
07-02 06:08:36.254: E/SoundPool(381): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
07-02 06:08:36.254: W/AudioService(381): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
07-02 06:08:36.274: E/SoundPool(381): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
07-02 06:08:36.274: W/AudioService(381): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
07-02 06:08:36.274: E/SoundPool(381): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
07-02 06:08:36.284: W/AudioService(381): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
07-02 06:08:36.324: W/AudioService(381): onLoadSoundEffects(), Error -1 while loading samples
07-02 06:08:36.484: I/Choreographer(1104): Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-02 06:08:38.174: I/Choreographer(381): Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-02 06:08:38.204: I/ActivityManager(381): Displayed com.example.trucktracker/.Locator: +1s804ms
07-02 06:08:38.474: I/Choreographer(381): Skipped 40 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-02 06:08:38.624: I/Choreographer(381): Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please remove this

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_locator);
```

from the

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
```

You are basically recreating every view in the activity each time a menu is opened. Which means your textLat and textLong variables are no longer valid. Any value you set into them will not be reflected in the app

Comment: i use that code to open the locator.activity from a button in the main_activity

Comment: but why do you have that code in the locator.activity?

Comment: wait no that fixed it; i moved it to the oncreate() method and everything is fine; thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

First thing to check-  is GPS enabled?

Second thing to check-  are you getting a location lock?  Do you see the GPS symbol appear on your notification bar?  If so is it flashing or stable?  If it isn't appearing, GPS isn't turning on at all.  If its flashing, you don't have a lock.  Until you have a lock, it won't call onLocationChanged.  Please note if you're inside you may never get a lock.

Another thing you can do is add MOCK_LOCATIONS to your permissions and download a mock location app.  It will fake the GPS data to your app for testing purposes.  If you do this, remember to remove that permission before release.

Comment: when i test it out on an actuall device and im outside it constantly shows the gps symbol flashing without any lock